# Mass Ai Unreal 5.1 lost skeletal meshes updating from 5.0

Tags: unreal-engine5

Hy guys, I was making practice with the Mass Ai in a project, and I  upgraded from ue5 to ue 5.1. Well I've lost the crowd!
Ue 5.1 doesn't seem to find the meshes to build its different characters on Mass Ai.
Can someone help me? [here's the log error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZcNR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to add two plugins namely:- Alembic Groom Importer and Hair modeling Toolset.